# Nop Commerce automatically redirecting to different URL

Tags: .htaccess, web-config, redirect, nopcommerce

I am having a very peculiar issue. For some specific url nop website redirects to another url. For example -

This is the url that is supposed to go -

[image]

when clicked or even pasted in address bar, I debugged the code and in the `application_beginrequest` method notice the url -

[image]
 (notice the **Path** property of **Request** object)

It automatically changed from `category_whisky-american-sour-mash` to `shipping-and-returns`. Checked both the SEO urls from category and page but no duplicates.

I checked for SEO urls and there is only one entry, so no possible way of duplication

[image]

I am trying to solve this for almost a day now. Can anybody help? Why is this happening? I am relatively new to NopCommerce. Any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, after one and half day of trying I finally found the fix. I thought I should post the solution here.

It is due to wrong `Slug` values. In the `UrlRecordService` this method caches the slug by putting `""` if no slug found -

```
    public virtual string GetActiveSlug(int entityId, string entityName, int languageId)
        {
            if (_localizationSettings.LoadAllUrlRecordsOnStartup)
            {
                string key = string.Format(URLRECORD_ACTIVE_BY_ID_NAME_LANGUAGE_KEY, entityId, entityName, languageId);
                return _cacheManager.Get(key, () =>
                {
                    //load all records (we know they are cached)
                    var source = GetAllUrlRecordsCached();
                    var query = from ur in source
                                where ur.EntityId == entityId &&
                                ur.EntityName == entityName &&
                                ur.LanguageId == languageId &&
                                ur.IsActive
                                orderby ur.Id descending
                                select ur.Slug;
                    var slug = query.FirstOrDefault();
                    //little hack here. nulls aren't cacheable so set it to ""
                    if (slug == null)
                        slug = ""; //slug is blank for null
                    return slug;
                });
            }
            else
            {
                //gradual loading
                string key = string.Format(URLRECORD_ACTIVE_BY_ID_NAME_LANGUAGE_KEY, entityId, entityName, languageId);
                return _cacheManager.Get(key, () =>
                {
                    var source = _urlRecordRepository.Table;
                    var query = from ur in source
                                where ur.EntityId == entityId &&
                                ur.EntityName == entityName &&
                                ur.LanguageId == languageId &&
                                ur.IsActive
                                orderby ur.Id descending
                                select ur.Slug;
                    var slug = query.FirstOrDefault();
                    //little hack here. nulls aren't cacheable so set it to ""
                    if (slug == null)
                        slug = ""; // slug is blank for null
                    return slug;
                });
            }
        }
```

Which ends creating a lot of urls with blank slugs. To fix this, you should do the followings -

1. First modify the code that converts slug to item so that it ignore blanks - 
   and
2. then add check to ignore slugs with `isActive = False` -

   ```
   public virtual UrlRecordForCaching GetBySlugCached(string slug)
   {
       if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(slug))
           return null;

       if (_localizationSettings.LoadAllUrlRecordsOnStartup)
       {
           //load all records (we know they are cached)
           var source = GetAllUrlRecordsCached();
           var query = from ur in source
                       where ur.Slug.Equals(slug, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
                       && ur.IsActive // 2 add IsActive check
                       select ur;
           var urlRecordForCaching = query.FirstOrDefault();
           return urlRecordForCaching;
       }
       else
       {
           //gradual loading
           string key = string.Format(URLRECORD_BY_SLUG_KEY, slug);
           return _cacheManager.Get(key, () =>
           {
               if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(slug))  // 1 blank slug check
                   return null;

               var urlRecord = GetBySlug(slug);
               if (urlRecord == null)
                   return null;

               var urlRecordForCaching = Map(urlRecord);
               return urlRecordForCaching;
           });
       }
   }



   /// <summary>
   /// Gets all URL records
   /// </summary>
   /// <param name="slug">Slug</param>
   /// <param name="pageIndex">Page index</param>
   /// <param name="pageSize">Page size</param>
   /// <returns>Customer collection</returns>
   public virtual IPagedList<UrlRecord> GetAllUrlRecords(string slug, int pageIndex, int pageSize)
   {
       var query = _urlRecordRepository.Table;
       if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(slug))
           query = query.Where(ur => ur.Slug.Contains(slug) && ur.IsActive); // 2 add IsActive check
       query = query.OrderBy(ur => ur.Slug);

       var urlRecords = new PagedList<UrlRecord>(query, pageIndex, pageSize);
       return urlRecords;
   }

   /// <summary>
   /// Find URL record
   /// </summary>
   /// <param name="slug">Slug</param>
   /// <returns>Found URL record</returns>
   public virtual UrlRecord GetBySlug(string slug)
   {
       if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(slug))
           return null;

       var query = from ur in _urlRecordRepository.Table
                   where ur.Slug == slug && ur.IsActive // 2 add IsActive check
                   select ur;
       var urlRecord = query.FirstOrDefault();
       return urlRecord;
   }


   protected virtual IList<UrlRecordForCaching> GetAllUrlRecordsCached()
   {
       //cache
       string key = string.Format(URLRECORD_ALL_KEY);
       return _cacheManager.Get(key, () =>
       {
           var query = from ur in _urlRecordRepository.Table
                       where ur.IsActive # 2 add IsActive check
                       select ur;
           var urlRecords = query.ToList();
           var list = new List<UrlRecordForCaching>();
           foreach (var ur in urlRecords)
           {
               var urlRecordForCaching = Map(ur);
               list.Add(urlRecordForCaching);
           }
           return list;
       });
   }


   /// <summary>
   /// Gets all cached URL records
   /// </summary>
   /// <returns>cached URL records</returns>
   protected virtual IList<UrlRecordForCaching> GetAllUrlRecordsCached()
   {
       //cache
       string key = string.Format(URLRECORD_ALL_KEY);
       return _cacheManager.Get(key, () =>
       {
           var query = from ur in _urlRecordRepository.Table
                       where ur.IsActive // 2 add isActive check
                       select ur;
           var urlRecords = query.ToList();
           var list = new List<UrlRecordForCaching>();
           foreach (var ur in urlRecords)
           {
               var urlRecordForCaching = Map(ur);
               list.Add(urlRecordForCaching);
           }
           return list;
       });
   }
   ```
3. Also don't forget to clear cookie and restart your server just in case.

So, far this solved my problem.